# What are those dates of financial reports means?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, annual-report, quarterly-report

There's graph showing the history of financial reports, for example the `revenue`. **Each point has some date, what exactly that date is?**

Below are pictures of historical reports for `revenue` for MCDonald's Annual and Quarterly reports.

The **annual report** has `2012-12-26` as a date. I suppose financial year for MCDonald's ends at `2012-12-31`. How report could have date that's earlier than the financial year end date? What those date means?

The **quarterly report** has `2012-09-24` as a date. Again, I suppose the Q3 for MCDonald's ends at `2012-09-30`. How report could have date that's earlier than the Q3 end date?

[image]
[image]

[Full Graph](https://www.gurufocus.com/chart/MCD?fp=q#&serie=,,id:Revenue_2,s:NYSE:MCD,,id:Revenue_2,s:NYSE:MCD&startDate=1407454756000&endDate=1565221156000) click Annual/Quarterly button to switch between, top left in the toolbar of the graph. About the data source - I believe GuruFocus uses Morningstar as a provider.

Answer (score 1):

The quarterly reports cannot be released before the end of the quarter.

Here's a [link](https://www.zacks.com/stock/research/mcd/earnings-announcements) to the dates for McDonald's earnings announcements.  They are within a month of the end of the quarter.

Comment: Thank you! I see Zacks have different quarterly report announcement date `2012-10-19` which makes sense. Do you know what's the date on that chart picture `2012-09-24` from GuruFocus means then?

Comment: Your link didn't open the same chart as you posted in your question.  I have no clue what that date represents.  Contact Gurufocus or start googling the dates in question and see if it shows a pattern.

Comment: I believe it opens same graph, annual revenue, with different scale on timeline (my version is zoomed in). There's no way to provide link to exactly the same graph, it resets it every time you open the page.